# Column values to dynamically define struct

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two nested arrays one is strings the other are floats.  I would like to essentially zip this up and have one (value, var) combo per row.  I was trying to do it with just a dataframe and not have to resort to rdds or udfs thinking that this would be cleaner and faster.

I can turn array of values, variables per row into a struct of a value, variable, 1-per-row, but because my array sizes vary I have to run my array comprehension over different ranges.  So I thought I could just specify the length in a column and use that.  But because I would be using a column it's a syntax error.  Any suggestions on how to use a column to dynamically build a struct like this (without rdd/udf if possible)?:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, array, struct, explode

DF1 = spark.createDataFrame([(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], [1,2,3,4,5,6], 6),
                             (["g"], [7], 1),
                             (["a", "b", "g", "c"], [4,5,3,6], 4),
                             (["c", "d"], [2,3], 2),
                             (["a", "b", "c"], [5,7,2], 3)],
                            ["vars", "vals", "num_elements"])
DF1.show()

arrayofstructs = array(*[struct(
  DF1.vars[c].alias("variables"),
  DF1.vals[c].alias("values")
#) for c in DF1.num_elements]) # <- DOES NOT WORK
) for c in range(10)])         # <- FIXED SIZE DOES WORK

DF2 = DF1.withColumn("new", explode(arrayofstructs))
DF2.show()

DF3 = DF2.filter(DF2.new.variables.isNotNull())
DF3.show()


+------------------+------------------+------------+
|              vars|              vals|num_elements|
+------------------+------------------+------------+
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|
|               [g]|               [7]|           1|
|      [a, b, g, c]|      [4, 5, 3, 6]|           4|
|            [c, d]|            [2, 3]|           2|
|         [a, b, c]|         [5, 7, 2]|           3|
+------------------+------------------+------------+

+------------------+------------------+------------+------+
|              vars|              vals|num_elements|   new|
+------------------+------------------+------------+------+
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|[a, 1]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|[b, 2]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|[c, 3]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|[d, 4]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|[e, 5]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|[f, 6]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|   [,]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|   [,]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|   [,]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|   [,]|
|               [g]|               [7]|           1|[g, 7]|
|               [g]|               [7]|           1|   [,]|
|               [g]|               [7]|           1|   [,]|
|               [g]|               [7]|           1|   [,]|
|               [g]|               [7]|           1|   [,]|
|               [g]|               [7]|           1|   [,]|
|               [g]|               [7]|           1|   [,]|
|               [g]|               [7]|           1|   [,]|
|               [g]|               [7]|           1|   [,]|
|               [g]|               [7]|           1|   [,]|
+------------------+------------------+------------+------+
only showing top 20 rows

+------------------+------------------+------------+------+
|              vars|              vals|num_elements|   new|
+------------------+------------------+------------+------+
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|[a, 1]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|[b, 2]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|[c, 3]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|[d, 4]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|[e, 5]|
|[a, b, c, d, e, f]|[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]|           6|[f, 6]|
|               [g]|               [7]|           1|[g, 7]|
|      [a, b, g, c]|      [4, 5, 3, 6]|           4|[a, 4]|
|      [a, b, g, c]|      [4, 5, 3, 6]|           4|[b, 5]|
|      [a, b, g, c]|      [4, 5, 3, 6]|           4|[g, 3]|
|      [a, b, g, c]|      [4, 5, 3, 6]|           4|[c, 6]|
|            [c, d]|            [2, 3]|           2|[c, 2]|
|            [c, d]|            [2, 3]|           2|[d, 3]|
|         [a, b, c]|         [5, 7, 2]|           3|[a, 5]|
|         [a, b, c]|         [5, 7, 2]|           3|[b, 7]|
|         [a, b, c]|         [5, 7, 2]|           3|[c, 2]|
+------------------+------------------+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to hack something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, lit, posexplode, expr, split

(DF1
    .select("*", posexplode(split(expr("repeat('_', num_elements - 1)"), '_')))
    .select(col("vars").getItem(col("pos")),col("vals").getItem(col("pos")))
    .show())

# +---------+---------+
# |vars[pos]|vals[pos]|
# +---------+---------+
# |        a|        1|
# |        b|        2|
# |        c|        3|
# |        d|        4|
# |        e|        5|
# |        f|        6|
# |        g|        7|
# |        a|        4|
# |        b|        5|
# |        g|        3|
# |        c|        6|
# |        c|        2|
# |        d|        3|
# |        a|        5|
# |        b|        7|
# |        c|        2|
# +---------+---------+
```

but it is anything but "cleaner and faster". Personally I would use `RDD`:

```py
(DF1.rdd
    .flatMap(lambda row: ((val, var) for val, var in zip(row.vals, row.vars)))
    .toDF(["val", "var"])
    .show())

# +---+---+
# |val|var|
# +---+---+
# |  1|  a|
# |  2|  b|
# |  3|  c|
# |  4|  d|
# |  5|  e|
# |  6|  f|
# |  7|  g|
# |  4|  a|
# |  5|  b|
# |  3|  g|
# |  6|  c|
# |  2|  c|
# |  3|  d|
# |  5|  a|
# |  7|  b|
# |  2|  c|
# +---+---+
```

but `udf` will work as well.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response.  Would there be a way to do this but just append the column to the original dataframe?

Comment: In the first approach  - `.select("*", col("vars").getItem(col("pos")),col("vals").getItem(col("pos")))`, in the second `.flatMap(lambda row: ((row, val, var) for val, var in zip(row.vals, row.vars))).toDF(["data", "val", "var"])`.

Answer (score 0):

***Using SQL DDL schema format is another alternative.***

I have a similar problem in Scala, where we struggled so much to create a dynamic nested structure using case classes. A few days prior, I attended Databricks courses where I learned about a different approach and I'm not sure why nobody is talking about this approch.

The easiest method to make it dynamic is to feed SQL DDL from the configuration file.
Because this method uses SQL DDL, it may be applied to both Scala spark and Pyspark.

An example of how that actually appears is presented below.

**Schema Using Structs.**

```
StructType([
    StructField(“field1”,  StringType(), true )
    StructField(“field2”, StructType([ 
        StructField(“field3”,  DoubleType(), true )
        StructField(“field4”,  LongType(), true )
    ])
```

**Schema Using SQL DDL.**

```
DDL_Schema =  " 'field1’ STRING, ‘field2’ STRUCT< 'field3’: DOUBLE, 'field4’: BIGINT>"
```

**Creating data frame using SQL DDL**

```
spark.read.schema (DDLSchema)•json(eventsJsonPath)
```

I hope that this may assist with a number of problems involving dynamic structure.

**Please refer to this page for more information.** https://vincent.doba.fr/posts/20211004_spark_data_description_language_for_defining_spark_schema/

Thank you