# pyspark create multiple rows from a list of comma separated values

Tags: pyspark, tweets

In pyspark sqlcontext sql, have written code to get text and then reformat it
But something like this is the issue

Having something in the dataframe like this
where the code is like

```python
hash_tags_fun = udf(lambda t: re.findall('(#[^#]\w{3,})', t))

hash_tags_in_tweets_df.registerTempTable("hash_tags_table")
hash_tags_result = sqlContext.sql("SELECT text FROM hash_tags_table")
hash_tags_list = hash_tags_result.withColumn('text', hash_tags_fun('text'))
hash_tags_list.show(3)
+-------------------+
|               text|
+-------------------+
|  [#shutUpAndDANCE]|
|  [#SHINee, #AMBER]|
|[#JR50, #flipagram]|
+-------------------+
```

I need something like

```python
+-------------------+
|               text|
+-------------------+
|    #shutUpAndDANCE|
|            #SHINee|
|             #AMBER|
|              #JR50|
|         #flipagram|
+-------------------+
```

```python
hash_tags_list.withColumn("text", explode("text")) has given an error saying
```

> AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'explode(`text`)' due to data type
>   mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not
>   string;; \n'Project [explode(text#24) AS text#68]\n+-
>   AnalysisBarrier\n
>   +- Project [(text#9) AS text#24]\n
>   +- Project [text#9]\n
>   +- SubqueryAlias hash_tags_table\n
>   +- Project [text#9]\n
>   +- Filter text#9 LIKE %#%\n
>   +- SubqueryAlias twt\n
>   +- SubqueryAlias tweets\n
>   +- Relation[country#6,id#7,place#8,text#9,user#10] json\n"

Comment: check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50378312/column-values-to-dynamically-define-struct

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explode in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38210507/explode-in-pyspark)

Comment: You have a string column. You're going to have to remove the brackets and then split on comma. Then you can explode. You can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace) and [`pyspark.sql.functions.split()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.split)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expanding on [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50458786/pyspark-create-multiple-rows-from-a-list-of-comma-separated-values#comment87952935_50458786):

Your column looks like an array but it is actually a string- this is why your call to `explode()` didn't work. You will have to convert the column to an array first.

This will involve removing the leading and trailing square brackets and splitting on the comma character.

First to remove the leading and trailing brackets, you can use [`pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, split
df = hash_tags_list.select(regexp_replace("text", r"(^\[)|(\]$)", "").alias("text"))
df.show()
#+-----------------+
#|             text|
#+-----------------+
#|  #shutUpAndDANCE|
#|  #SHINee, #AMBER|
#|#JR50, #flipagram|
#+-----------------+
```

Now split on the comma followed by a space:

```python
df = df.select(split("text", ", ").alias("text"))
df.show()
#+-------------------+
#|               text|
#+-------------------+
#|  [#shutUpAndDANCE]|
#|  [#SHINee, #AMBER]|
#|[#JR50, #flipagram]|
#+-------------------+
```

You'll notice that this *prints* exactly like what you started with, but when we inspect the schema we see that these are actually arrays of strings:

```python
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- text: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

Compare this with your original DataFrame's schema:

```python
hash_tags_list.printSchema()
#root
# |-- text: string (nullable = true)
```

Having the data as an array, makes calling `explode()` now possible:

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
df = df.select(explode("text").alias("hashtags"))
df.show()
#+---------------+
#|       hashtags|
#+---------------+
#|#shutUpAndDANCE|
#|        #SHINee|
#|         #AMBER|
#|          #JR50|
#|     #flipagram|
#+---------------+
```